# Do I need more memory for my CentOS server?

Tags: linux, centos, memory-usage

When checking my server's memory usage with **free -m** I'm getting this result:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024       1024          0          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:       1024          0
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Every answer I found to similar questions tried to point out that you have to look at the buffers/cache row with examples showing only part of the memory was actually really used.

On my server though it looks like the memory is 100% in use.

Am I getting something wrong here or should I upgrade my server ASAP?

Comment: Yes, you need more memory. Unless you are running exactly at capacity, (unlikely) you should be seeing OOM Killer thrashing your processes. Look at `dmesg`, or wherever you have Kernel logs directed. Is this not the case?

Comment: With absolutely zero memory remaining I'm really surprised you're still able to execute that command. But yes you definitely need more memory and if possible find out what process ate it all.

Comment: dmesg didn't return anything; as it's on a GoDaddy VPS I assume I won't be able to see it.  I did just upgrade the server to 2Gb and I now have 790Mb free.  The processes eating my memory were clamd and amavisd... like you could guess, on a mail server.

Thank you for the quick responses!!

Comment: @Dominique you should really look into Clam's and Amavis's configuration to make it use less RAM, and possibly add an 1Gb swap partition just in case. Oh and finally, consider switching to a *decent* VPS provider (Linode, DigitalOcean, OVH, etc).

Comment: @AndréDaniel  The reason I was looking into the mail server's memory usage is because I'm planning on moving it to Digital Ocean shortly.  I'll also be upgrading the server to all the latest versions of the software... so thank you for the advice, it will all be taken care of ;)